# What is the use of Eclipse RCP in applications?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I will like to understand what is the scenario that Eclipse RCP is best suited for your application? What are better alternatives?

Comment: Sorry but this is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @greg-449 please let me know right platform where my question can be answered.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312461/starting-working-with-eclipse-rcp